# mdframed incompatible with paralist

Tags: incompatibility, mdframed, paralist

Compare `mdframed` with boxed `minipage` in the following example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[neveradjust]{paralist}%
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
%\begin{boxedminipage}{125mm}
\begin{mdframed}
    \begin{asparaenum}[\bfseries i.]%i, ii, iii.

\begin{minipage}[t]{72mm}       
    \item%i
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t]{72mm}       
    \item%ii
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
\end{minipage}

    \end{asparaenum}%i, ii, iii.
%\end{boxedminipage}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `\leavevmode` before `asparaenum` seems to fix the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[neveradjust]{paralist}%
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}
\leavevmode\begin{asparaenum}[\bfseries i.]%i, ii, iii.
\begin{minipage}[t]{72mm}       
    \item%i
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t]{72mm}       
    \item%ii
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
\end{minipage}
\end{asparaenum}%i, ii, iii.
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Addendum (as per OP's request):

the solution proposed works with the current versions of the packages (as of August 6, 2013):

```
paralist.sty    2013/06/09 v2.4 Extended list environments
mdframed.sty    2013/07/01 1.9b: mdframed
```

In chat I asked for confirmation of this fact: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10662206#10662206

and users **Paulo Cereda** and **Werner** independently verified the need for `\leavevmode`.

In comments, initially a system update was suggested and OP's claims that after updating his system, `\leavevmode` is not required.

Comment: Does not work here.(TeXLive-2012 with TeXShop 2.47 under 10.5.8 on PowerPC G4). Only LaTeX warning is: You have requested, on input line 72, version
               `2011/01/03' of package etoolbox,
               but only version
               `2010/09/12 v2.0a e-TeX tools for LaTeX'
               is available.
(But the source ends at line 21)

Comment: @schremmer using an updated TeXLive 2013 installation the code works. I'd suggest you to update your LaTeX installation.

Comment: @Medina I upgraded to 2013 and mdframed and paralist lived together happily ever after even without \leavevmode. (At least until TeXLive 2014). Thank you very, very much.

Comment: @schremmer with the current versions of the packages `\leavevmode` appears to be necessary.

Comment: %Swann Here, with or without \leavevmode, it does not work under TeXLive 2012 and does work under TeXLive 2013. (I am using the TeX Distribution switcher.)

Comment: @Medina I asked "Real answer appeared in the discussion that followed the original answer" and got in return that you "might update [your] answer". Sorry about all that but I am a complete novice here. (By the way, it works under 2013 in the original situation and not just in the minimal example I gave. So, again, thanks very much.)

Comment: @schremmer I added a little addendum to my answer.

Comment: @schremmer Incase you have heavy usage on these two packages, may be use latest(2013) [`paralist.sty`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/paralist) and [`mdframed.sty`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed) from ctan and place them in the working folder to take precedence instead of TeXLive 2012 old `.sty` files. Updating to Latest TL is always a preferred option (to be in sync with all TeX people and systems) but left to personal choice :).

Comment: @Medina I "accepted" your answer and would thank you again for solving my problem.

Comment: @texenthusiast I do make heavy use of both paralist.sty and mdframed.sty and everything now works (under TL 2013). Updating TL used to be a pain because I always had to use the terminal to change a setting. This time was OK (I used TextWrangler). Thanks to everybody for everything.